# Is there a way to manually export testng test results from a function and not clicking the button?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, export, automated-tests, testng

I am working in with Java in intelliJ and have a testSuite that I would eventually like to be able to automatically run, export test results to file, and email those results to my boss. The test runs and the e-mail sends with the attachment. I just can't seem to figure out if there is a certain method that I can implement to do such a thing.

Comment: What do you mean, 'automatically'?

Comment: I will be putting my test files in Jenkinds as @yole had suggested, which will then run the tests as I want them to. The only problem that I am having here is with the "export test results"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by installing a continuous integration server, which will monitor your version control system, run the tests every time you commit code, and send the notifications according to your configuration (for example, by sending an email to your boss if that's what you need).

Popular continuous integration servers include [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity).

Comment: Thank you @yole ,  I will be using these under Jenkins, but the problem is simply with being able to code in a command that executes the "export test results" function within the code.

Comment: You can write a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA that will invoke the "export test results" function. However, I don't quite understand why you would need that if you're going to use Jenkins - all the test result management will be automatically taken care of by Jenkins.

Comment: Okay, wonderful. I'm decently new to this job and Jenkins as well, but Jenkins seems like a nice guy.